# Does IIS cache assemblies and do I have to recycle the App Pool on deploy

Tags: caching, iis, assemblies

I've never really been sure if you have to force an App Pool recycle on IIS after copying a new DLL to the bin path but I normally do it just to be sure. If a new assembly is copied into the bin path I thought that IIS would recache if it has a new version. The assembly is not in the GAC or any other location.

I received an error about an SQL parameter that was expected by the SP but was not provided. The app pool in this instance was not recycled and the deployment has now been rolled back so I can't simply recycle the app pool to try it.

Does anyone have any links to explain assembly caching in IIS as I can't quite find what I'm looking for.

Note the deployment is a very manual process of manually copying binaries using Windows Explorer onto the prod servers